# Can I assign a prototype method of one constructor to the prototype method of another?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

For instance, in the below example I would like there to be an easily accessible property on the `Success()` constructor called `padded` which will use the `log` method on the `Padded()` constructor.

If so, how do I go about doing this? It's a contrived example, but I'm trying to properly understand prototypal inheritance.

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding how to use prototypal inheritance & inheritance in general?

What I'm trying to achieve here is the functionality in APIs like [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) e.g. You can string objects together such as `chalk.blue.bgRed.bold('string')`. How are these strung together? Each being useable on there own too – `chalk.blue('string')`

```js
function Message(message) {
  this.message = message
}

Message.prototype.log = function() {
  if (this.color) {
    console.log('<' + this.color + '>', this.message)
  } else {
    console.log(this.message)
  }
}

// Padded
function Padded(message) {
  Message.call(this, message)
  this.padded = true
}

Padded.prototype = Object.create(Message.prototype)
Padded.prototype.constructor = Padded

Padded.prototype.log = function() {
  console.log(`\n${this.message}\n`)
}

// Success
function Success(message) {
  Message.call(this, message)
  this.color = 'green'
}

Success.prototype = Object.create(Message.prototype)

// Here I try to assign one prototype property to another. Which does not work.
Success.prototype.padded = Padded.prototype.log

Success.prototype.constructor = Success

// Error
function Error(message) {
  Message.call(this, message)
  this.color = 'red'
}

Error.prototype = Object.create(Message.prototype)
Error.prototype.constructor = Error


const log = {
  success: (msg) => new Success(msg).log(),
  error: (msg) => new Error(msg).log()
}

// Here I want to be able to 'pad' a log by accessing the `padded` property on the `Success.prototype` object.

//log.success.padded('test success')
log.success('Test success')
log.error('test error')
```

Comment: I see that you are using string interpolation and arrow functions from ES6. why not use the `class` syntax to implement the inheritance? it's going to be the same prototypal inheritance under the hood.

Comment: I will do once I understand how this works, this is just making it easier for me to reason about while I learn.

Comment: The clue to chain them together is returning `this` in each setter, so you receive the instance back after the setter. So if function `blue` sets some state inside the instance and returns it, you can then chain the next method `bgRed` to it. So if you add function padded to the prototype of Message nad have it return 'this', you can use `message.padded( 'someString' ).log();`

Comment: Chaining doesn’t have anything to do with inheritance or prototypes. Why don’t you just look at chalk’s code? It’s open source after all.

Comment: Ok I think I have a better understanding of this now, and realise they're not connected. Thanks Shilly + Felix

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I still don't understand how you can chain methods without using parentheses. E.g. `chalk.red('string')` will print a red string and `chalk.red.bgGreen('string')` will print a red string with a green background. How are they both methods and objects with child methods on them at the same time?

I have read over Chalks source code and I still can't make sense of it.

Comment: Every function is an object.